# Different values for a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have lots of single Addresses that have different Sq_ft values in them (this should not be the case). I want to parse through the columns that have different values for Sq_Ft for the same address. What can I add to the where clause which would assist me in doing this? I have tried adding the distinct syntax with Sq_ft but futile.

Example:

```
Address of New Home                      Sq_Ft
1234 Obama Drive                         2,578
1234 Obama Drive                         2,586

select "Address_of_New_Home","Sq_Ft"
from "Amazon".salesdatapcr
where "Sq_Ft" <>
order by 1
```

Comment: Perform a self join on the address then compare <> sq_ft. `select A."Address_of_New_Home",A."Sq_Ft"
from "Amazon".salesdatapcr A
INNER JOIN "Amazon".salesdatapcr B on A."Address_of_New_Home" = B."Address_of_New_Home" and A.Sq_Ft <> B.Sq_Ft
order by 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `EXISTS` operator and a correlated subquery:

```
select "Address_of_New_Home","Sq_Ft"
from "Amazon".salesdatapcr t1
where EXISTS (
   SELECT null from "Amazon".salesdatapcr t2
   WHERE t1."Address_of_New_Home" = t2."Address_of_New_Home"
     and t1."Sq_Ft" <> t2."Sq_Ft"
)
order by 1
```

Comment: I do not know which one to mark correct. Both are awesome answers.

Comment: If you don't know then just flip a coin to decide which answer to mark.

Answer (score 2):

This would list rows from a table for which there are more than one occurences of an address with different sq_ft:

```
SELECT salesdt.*
FROM "Amazon".salesdatapcr salesdt
JOIN (
  SELECT
    "Address_of_New_Home" AS home_address
  FROM
    "Amazon".salesdatapcr
  GROUP BY 1
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT "Sq_Ft") > 1
  ) multisqft ON
    salesdt."Address_of_New_Home" = multisqft.home_address
ORDER BY multisqft.home_address
```

You could just as well use `EXISTS` or `IN` to achieve this. `ORDER` is there to make things clearer.

Comment: I do not know which one to mark correct. Both are awesome answers.